# Open alert dialog box after clicking on button in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am beginners for Angular2, I want to show pop with two options Yes and No on button click.
  When clicked the yes options main div hide and after click on No options,Dialog box should hide.

Here is the sample code.

```html
index.html

<div id="main">
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>

</div>




hello.component.ts

import {Component, View} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './index.html',
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also just starting to learn Angular 2... and also starting out on StackOverflow.  But I believe that something along these lines would work.  Also, I'm just freehanding this, so forgive if my syntax is not 100% accurate.

```
<div id="main" *ngIf="displayMain">
    <button type="button" (click)="OpenConfirm">Click Me!</button>

</div>


<div id="confirmBox" [class.visible]="DisplayDialogBox">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <button (click)="ClickYes">Yes</button>
    <button (click)="ClickNo">No</button>
</div>
```

Handle the click events in your Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './index.html',
})
export class MyApplicationComponent{
    displayConfirmBox = false;
    displayMain = true;

    OpenConfirm(){
       this.displayConfirmBox = true;
    }

    ClickYes(){
       this.displayMain=false;
    }

    ClickNo(){
       this.DisplayDialogBox = false;
    }

}
```

CSS

```
 #confirmBox{
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    border:1px solid black;
    opacity:0;
}

#confirmBox.visible{  
    opacity:1;  
}
#confirmBox .message{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:24px;
}

#confirmBox button{
    width:80px;
}
#confirmBox button:first-child{
    float:left;
}
#confirmBox button:last-child{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't create popup dialog.

Comment: edited code and added CSS to make the confirmBox display as a popup

Comment: Revisited this old post...  built out in StackBlitz.  Fixed a couple syntax issues (as I had noted that there may be as I typed it out on my phone IIRC) and it seemed to fit your request.  Thanks for the downvote though

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kjszj4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)